# How to remove the extra padding at the beginning and end of android viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I want to remove the extra padding/margin at the viewpager. See attached image here https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsqzae28mvihy96/Screenshot_2015-07-22-17-59-30.png?dl=0

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.masterscroll.masterscroll.CommunityActivity2"
    android:padding="0dp">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Could you provide your layout xml ?

Comment: check if the parent of the viewpager has paddings defined and remove them.

Comment: post your layout xml

Comment: We need to see your full XML. Maybe you have padding in your parent Layout.

Comment: This is the layout for the activity containing the ViewPager. In other words, this is the parent layout

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073002/how-to-set-padding-between-viewpager-pages-while-keeping-the-page-full-width) answer. You can try these methods on your ViewPager.

```
setPageMargin(int marginPixels)
setPageMarginDrawable(drawable d)
setPageMarginDrawable(int resId)
```